# Enforce only one space isntead of several when space-before-blocks is enabled in eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint

How can properly configure a rule to enforce that before a code block with braces it only contains one single space instead several spaces or tabs?

So far I have been using:

```
/* globals isCorrect, aValue callback */
/*eslint space-before-blocks: "error"*/

if (isCorrect)  { // That should be incorrect, more than one space
    callback('correct');
} else if(aValue == 5) { // That should be correct, only one space
    callback('aValue');
} else      { // That is also incorrect, tabs!
    callback('incorrect');
}
```

Comment: I dont think there is a core rule for this. I havent looked for plugins which might have this rule. You can always create your custom rule inside your plugin if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`no-multi-spaces`](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-multi-spaces) for that! Add `/* no-multi-spaces: "error" */` to your example and try it in the [demo](http://eslint.org/demo):

```
/* globals isCorrect, aValue callback */
/* eslint space-before-blocks: "error" */
/* eslint no-multi-spaces: "error" */

if (isCorrect)  { // That should be incorrect, more than one space
    callback('correct');
} else if(aValue == 5) { // That should be correct, only one space
    callback('aValue');
} else      { // That is also incorrect, tabs!
    callback('incorrect');
}
```

That should give you the errors you want:

```
5:17 - Multiple spaces found before '{'. (no-multi-spaces)
9:13 - Multiple spaces found before '{'. (no-multi-spaces)
```

Comment: It works, however it only works if there are spaces. It does not consider 'tabs' as incorrect space. That fixes the problem partially :/

Comment: @JoséCabo I tried and it works for tabs too!